# Can you give me an easy real world example where a stochastic integral arises "naturally"?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, intuition

I have trouble getting comfortable with integration with respect to a stochastic process, because I somehow don't see what is happening when you do such an integration. I have a picture in my head for Riemann and Lebesgue integrals but the randomness here somehow makes such an integral kind of obscure for me. There was a post somewhere stating that stochastic integration is "kind of" Riemann-Stieltjes integration but with $\triangle x$ being a random variable, but I still can't wrap my head around that...

I think a good and easy example where such an integral arises naturally would really help me.

Comment: The stochastic integral can, at the most heuristic level, be thought of as Riemann-Stieltjes integration. Of course, the integrator tends to not have finite variation, but morally, that's the point.

Comment: I think the best probabilistic interpretation of the stochastic integral is "betting on a stochastic process in continuous time", where the stochastic process can be anything evolving with uncertainty, e.g. stock prices.

Comment: The discrete stochastic integral is an extremely natural object as a reward process associated to a discrete martingale. The continuous time integral is unnatural only in that the convergence of the easily constructed discretized processes to the continuous process does not take place in the conventional manner : otherwise, it's old wine in a new bottle, a reward process associated to the Brownian motion.

Comment: Harrison and Pliska wrote in their seminal 1981 paper *Martingales and stochastic integrals in continuous trading* "All of this is intended to suggest that the modern theory of martingales and 
stochastic integrals provides exactly the mathematical framework needed for a 
theory of continuous trading. As our development unfolds, there will be still more 
examples of general results in the mathematical theory that look as if they were 
created for this application."

Comment: [https://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture7_2019.pdf](https://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture7_2019.pdf) Here you have at least four examples